# SQL, 2 tables sum of a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, `student` and `family`.

Half of the students come Sundays, the other half Saturdays

Some families have more than one child.

Families pay fees for the school. Some families because of some critearia have a discount.

"discount" is a field in 'family' table

In a report I need to calculate the sum of all the discounts of all families that take advantage of a discount (by day).

When I do so, if a family has 2 children, the result returns double of the discount, if 3 children 3 x discount....

My Query:

```
$select_total_discounts = 
"SELECT SUM(Discount) AS total_discounts
FROM family, student
WHERE family.Family_ID=student.Family_ID
AND student.Day like '%$Day%'  ;" ; 

$query= mysql_query($select_total_discounts,$conn) ; 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$total_discounts= $row['total_discounts'];
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It would help if you post table schema too.

Comment: As well as the results you are getting and what you are expecting to get.

Comment: For me is pretty unclear. You say something for stundents, then go to Family asking for discount, but your query joins them and you did not explain that. Families' childs are students? Can a family have a child that is not a student? If you want the discount of a family, why not just select it ?

Comment: I presume the issue is that discounts are for a family, (and therefore should appear once) but are being included multiple times if the family has more than 1 child - is that correct? We could fix that, but you'll have a problem no matter what if a family has a child on each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to calculate the discounts by family disregarding the amount of students it has. So it'd be like this (change the day value by your variable):

```
SELECT SUM(Discount) AS total_discounts
FROM family 
WHERE family.Family_ID in (select student.Family_ID from student  where student.Day like 'Monday')
```

So it sums the discounts of the families that have at least one student from the specified day. If it has one, two, three or more students, it will not affect the result.

Working SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9793/1

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Many tanks

Answer (score -2):

It is not really full answer, but I posted it here, so it would be readable.

I think you are looking for something like `UNION`:

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM ((SELECT value FROM table) UNION ALL (SELECT value FROM table2)) sq
```

`UNION` merges your tables vertically.